# Safe passwords locally with node-webkit

Tags: node.js, security, passwords, local-storage, node-webkit

I have to save password locally in my application. Unfortunately I can't just hash them because I have to use it every time the application starts. Is there a possibility to save the password and keep all other programs away from opening it. I know from Android that you don't have to mind about this because the OS does everything. Is there also a possibility in node-webkit(Windows).

Thanks a lot in Advance!